# Add figure on right of Grid Layout

Tags: java

I am trying to add a figure on the right side of a gridlayout. The problem is that the figure is being considered as a part of the grid. I want it to be separately displayed on the right side of the grid in the same frame. I tried to make a different container but it did not work. Thanks

## Canvas.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class Canvas extends JFrame{
    public Canvas(){
        super("Canvas to draw");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700,700);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            pane.add(button);
        }
        FigurePane f = new FigurePane();
        pane.add(f);
    }
}
```

## FigurePane.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FigurePane extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics comp){
        Graphics2D comp2D =(Graphics2D)comp;
        GradientPaint p1=new      GradientPaint(2F,2F,Color.red,335F,335F,Color.blue);
        comp2D.setPaint(p1);
        comp2D.fillRect(2, 2, 335, 350);
        }
}
```

## Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest you use a GridBagLayout. It is more customizable than GridLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested panels with appropriate layout managers. For example:

```
JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout() );
FigurePanel figure = new FigurePanel();
JPanel main = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
main.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
main.add(figure, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also, don't call your class "Canvas". There is an AWT component with that name so it will be confusing. Use a more descriptive name.